# Android live wallpaper scaling

Tags: android, scaling

I'm learning android and java and am trying to learn how to make a live wallpaper
I am using the aquarium tutorial, I put it all in one file instead of spreading it but what I am trying to do is get one scale number for everything, I want to get the height of the screen divide that by the background image height (which will always be bigger), this should give me a ratio to use for scaling everything, I tried this in a surfaceView code and it worked perfect, I tried it in livewallpaper and nada.
In the surfaceView test I use onSizeChange and got the height that way and it worked no problems.
This is what I did for the livewallpaper one
This is what I put for the onSurfaceChange

```
public int screenWidth;
public float rescaler;
public float totalHeight = theTemplate._backgroundImage.getHeight();

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    //add rescale and width
    screenWidth = width;
    rescaler = (float) (height / totalHeight);
    super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);          
}
```

The background image comes from an inner class named TheTemplate
This is what I did there
The variables

```
private SpriteAnimationActivityEngine theTest;
private Bitmap theBackgroundImage;
private float theScaler = theTest.rescaler;
```

then I try and rescale it using theScaler

```
public void initialize(Context context, SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    this.spriteThread = new SpriteThread(this); 
    this._surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;        
    this._sprites = new ArrayList<Renderable>();
    this._context = context;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    this._backgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),ca.samsstuff.testonepagewallpaper.R.drawable.sky, options);
    this.theBackgroundImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(_backgroundImage,  (int) (theScaler * _backgroundImage.getWidth()),  (int) (theScaler * _backgroundImage.getHeight()), true);
    this.addSprites();
}
```

Then it passes it to draw the background

```
private void renderBackGround(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(this.theBackgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Which sends it to draw

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    this.renderBackGround(canvas);              
    for (Renderable renderable : this._sprites) {
        renderable.render(canvas);
    }
}
```

I keep getting errors and don't know what I am doing wrong. Like I said I am learning both android and java but this method worked in another test I did but I got the screen height from onSizeChange can I get the height by using onSurfaceChange?

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance
sam

EDIT 
I also tried to rescale within the theTemplate class just to see if it would work having everything within its own class and still having issues, I used the DisplayMetrics to get the screen height this time.
This might work if I can get it going properly.
Here is this attempt

```
public class TheTemplate {

        private SpriteThread spriteThread;  
        private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;   
        private ArrayList<Renderable> _sprites; 
        public Bitmap _backgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sky);;
        private Context _context;

        // add rescale stuff
        private Bitmap theBackgroundImage;
        private float theScaler = initFrameParams() / _backgroundImage.getHeight();
        private Bitmap oneBackImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(_backgroundImage,  (int) (theScaler * _backgroundImage.getWidth()),  (int) (theScaler * _backgroundImage.getHeight()), true);

        int initFrameParams()
        {
                            //get the screen height to use to rescale everything
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
            display.getMetrics(metrics);

            int screenHeight = display.getHeight();
            return screenHeight;


        }


        public void render(){
            Canvas canvas = null;
            try{

                canvas = this._surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (this._surfaceHolder) {
                    this.onDraw(canvas);
                }

            }finally{
                if(canvas != null){
                    this._surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }   
        }

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            this.renderBackGround(canvas);              
            for (Renderable renderable : this._sprites) {
                renderable.render(canvas);
            }
        };

        public void start(){
            this.spriteThread.switchOn();
        }

        public void stop(){
            boolean retry = true;
            this.spriteThread.switchOff();
            while (retry) {
                try {
                 this.spriteThread.join();
                    retry = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // we will try it again and again...
                }
            }
        }

        public int getLeft() {      
            return 0;
        }


        public int getRight() {
            return this.theBackgroundImage.getWidth();
        }

        public void initialize(Context context, SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            this.spriteThread = new SpriteThread(this); 
            this._surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;        
            this._sprites = new ArrayList<Renderable>();
            this._context = context;
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPurgeable = true;
            this.theBackgroundImage = oneBackImage;
            this.addSprites();
        }


        private void addSprites() {     
            Point startPoint = new Point(100, 100);
            this._sprites.add(new SpriteOne(this._context, this, startPoint, 90));
            Point startPoint1 = new Point(100, 300);
            this._sprites.add(new SpriteOne(this._context, this, startPoint1, 50));

            Point startPoint2 = new Point(200, 200);
            this._sprites.add(new SpriteOne(this._context, this, startPoint2, 15));
        }

        private void renderBackGround(Canvas canvas)
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(this.theBackgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
```

As I stated before any help would be appreciated.
Thanks again in advance
Sam

Edit  SOLVED Here is an answer I came up with, The rescale code is where the comments are
Hope this helps someone out.

```
public class TheTemplate {  

            private SpriteThread spriteThread;    
            private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;     
            private ArrayList<Renderable> _sprites;     
            public Bitmap _backgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sky);;  
            private Context _context;  

            // add rescale stuff  
            //private SpriteAnimationActivityEngine theTest;  
            private Bitmap theBackgroundImage;  
            private float totalHeight = _backgroundImage.getHeight();  
            private int screenSized = initFrameParams();  
            private float theScaler = (float) (screenSized / totalHeight);  

            private Bitmap oneBackImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(_backgroundImage,  (int) (theScaler * _backgroundImage.getWidth()),  (int) (theScaler * _backgroundImage.getHeight()), true);  


            int initFrameParams()  
            {  
                DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();  
                Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();  
                display.getMetrics(metrics);  

                int screenHeight = display.getHeight();  
                return screenHeight;  
            }  


            public void render(){  
                Canvas canvas = null;  
                try{  

                    canvas = this._surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);  
                    synchronized (this._surfaceHolder) {  
                        this.onDraw(canvas);  
                    }  

                }finally{  
                    if(canvas != null){  
                        this._surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);  
                    }  
                }     
            }  

            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {  
                this.renderBackGround(canvas);                
                for (Renderable renderable : this._sprites) {  
                    renderable.render(canvas);  
                }  
            };  

            public void start(){  
                this.spriteThread.switchOn();  
            }  

            public void stop(){  
                boolean retry = true;  
                this.spriteThread.switchOff();  
                while (retry) {  
                    try {  
                     this.spriteThread.join();  
                        retry = false;  
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
                        // we will try it again and again...  
                    }  
                }  
            }  

            public int getLeft() {        
                return 0;  
            }  


            public int getRight() {  
                return this.theBackgroundImage.getWidth();  
            }  

            public void initialize(Context context, SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {  
                this.spriteThread = new SpriteThread(this);   
                this._surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;          
                this._sprites = new ArrayList<Renderable>();  
                this._context = context;  
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();  
                options.inPurgeable = true;  
                this.theBackgroundImage = oneBackImage;  
                this.addSprites();  
            }  


            private void addSprites() {       
                Point startPoint = new Point(100, 100);  
                this._sprites.add(new SpriteOne(this._context, this, startPoint, 90));  
                Point startPoint1 = new Point(100, 300);  
                this._sprites.add(new SpriteOne(this._context, this, startPoint1, 50));  

                Point startPoint2 = new Point(200, 200);  
                this._sprites.add(new SpriteOne(this._context, this, startPoint2, 15));  
            }  

            private void renderBackGround(Canvas canvas)  
            {  
                canvas.drawBitmap(this.theBackgroundImage, 0, 0, null);  
            }  
        }
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer the question if you describe the errors you are getting.

Comment: Its ok I figured it out finally. heres where I posted the the answer to anyone who has issues rescaling for live wallpaper. http://www.coderanch.com/t/547461/Android/Mobile/Rescaling-images-android-livewallpaper  I dont know how to mark this as solved but its now solved

Comment: Please answer the question yourself with the contents of that link and then you can mark it as resolved.

Comment: heres the solution I made comments in the code where the recaling takes place. Hopes this helps out other folks aww need to put this into another post to fit it sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the answer to the original post, hope this helps someone.
Sam
Sorry about that folks, new to this method of using a forum
Here is the answer, I added comments in the code where I made the changes for scaling images.
This method can also be used for positioning also.
Here is the answer.

```
 public class TheTemplate {  

        private SpriteThread spriteThread;    
        private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;     
        private ArrayList<Renderable> _sprites;     
        public Bitmap _backgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sky);;  
        private Context _context;  

        // add rescale stuff  
        //private SpriteAnimationActivityEngine theTest;  
        private Bitmap theBackgroundImage;  
        private float totalHeight = _backgroundImage.getHeight();  
        private int screenSized = initFrameParams();  
        private float theScaler = (float) (screenSized / totalHeight);  

        private Bitmap oneBackImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(_backgroundImage,  (int) (theScaler * _backgroundImage.getWidth()),  (int) (theScaler * _backgroundImage.getHeight()), true);  


        int initFrameParams()  
        {  
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();  
            Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();  
            display.getMetrics(metrics);  

            int screenHeight = display.getHeight();  
            return screenHeight;  
        }  


        public void render(){  
            Canvas canvas = null;  
            try{  

                canvas = this._surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);  
                synchronized (this._surfaceHolder) {  
                    this.onDraw(canvas);  
                }  

            }finally{  
                if(canvas != null){  
                    this._surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);  
                }  
            }     
        }  

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {  
            this.renderBackGround(canvas);                
            for (Renderable renderable : this._sprites) {  
                renderable.render(canvas);  
            }  
        };  

        public void start(){  
            this.spriteThread.switchOn();  
        }  

        public void stop(){  
            boolean retry = true;  
            this.spriteThread.switchOff();  
            while (retry) {  
                try {  
                 this.spriteThread.join();  
                    retry = false;  
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
                    // we will try it again and again...  
                }  
            }  
        }  

        public int getLeft() {        
            return 0;  
        }  


        public int getRight() {  
            return this.theBackgroundImage.getWidth();  
        }  

        public void initialize(Context context, SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {  
            this.spriteThread = new SpriteThread(this);   
            this._surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;          
            this._sprites = new ArrayList<Renderable>();  
            this._context = context;  
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();  
            options.inPurgeable = true;  
            this.theBackgroundImage = oneBackImage;  
            this.addSprites();  
        }  


        private void addSprites() {       
            Point startPoint = new Point(100, 100);  
            this._sprites.add(new SpriteOne(this._context, this, startPoint, 90));  
            Point startPoint1 = new Point(100, 300);  
            this._sprites.add(new SpriteOne(this._context, this, startPoint1, 50));  

            Point startPoint2 = new Point(200, 200);  
            this._sprites.add(new SpriteOne(this._context, this, startPoint2, 15));  
        }  

        private void renderBackGround(Canvas canvas)  
        {  
            canvas.drawBitmap(this.theBackgroundImage, 0, 0, null);  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: It will be easier for people to find if you edit your question and move the solution to an answer. You can answer your own question and mark it as solved. It will be easier for people to find, and you will get the credit (reputation) if others think it is a good answer. The FAQ explains how to ask and answer questions http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: If you can answer your own question, please do so and accept your answer. Otherwise, this question will remain on our list of unanswered questions. This will likely be closed and eventually deleted if you don't provide an answer.